# Try to find better way to manipulate large, multiple txt files through multiple directory using Ruby script

Tags: ruby, file, directory, large-files

I'm working on collecting test measurement data from product in manufacturing environment.
The test measurement result of units under test are generated by the test system. It is in an 2Mb txt file and was keep in share folders separated by products.

The folder structure looks like...

```
LOGS
|-Product1
|  |-log_p1_1.txt
|  |-log_p1_2.txt
|  |..
|-Product2
|  |-log_p2_1.txt
|  |-log_p2_2.txt
|  |..
|-...
```

My ruby script can iterate through each Product directory under LOGS and then read each `log_px_n.txt` file, parse data I need in the file and update it into database.

The thing is that all log_px_n.txt files of must be keep in its current directory, both old file and new files, while I need to keep my database update as soon as the new `log_px_n.tx` file was generated.

what I did today is to try iterate through each Product directories then read each individual `.txt` file and after that update file into database if it was not exist.

My script looks like..

```
Dir['*'].each do |product|
  product_dir = File.join(BASE_DIR, product)
  Dir.chdir(product_dir)
     Dir['*.txt'].each do |log|
       if (Time.now - File.mtime(log) < SIX_HOURS_AGO)   # take only new files in last six hours
       # Here we do..
       # - read each 2Mb .txt file
       # - extract infomation from txt file
       # - update into database
     end
   end
end
```

There are upto 30 differents product directories and each product contain around 1000 `.txt` file (2Mb each), and they are growing !

I don't have issue about disk space to store such `.txt` file but the time it take to complete this operation. 
It takes >45min to complete task each time when run above code block.

Is there any better way to deal with this situation ?

Update:
I tried as Iced's suggest to use profiler, so I run below code and got following result...

```
require 'profiler'

class MyCollector

def initialize(dir, period, *filetypes)
    @dir = dir
    @filetypes = filetypes.join(',')
    @period = period
end

def collect
    Dir.chdir(@dir)
    Dir.glob('*').each do |product|
        products_dir = File.join(@dir, product)

        Dir.chdir(products_dir)
        puts "at product #{product}"

        Dir.glob("**/*.{#{@filetypes}}").each do |log|
            if Time.now - File.mtime(log) < @period
                puts Time.new
            end
        end
    end
end
path = '//10.1.2.54/Shares/Talend/PRODFILES/LOGS'
SIX_HOURS_AGO = 21600

Profiler__::start_profile
collector = MyCollector.new(path, SIX_HOURS_AGO, "LOG")
collector.collect
Profiler__::stop_profile
Profiler__::print_profile(STDOUT)
```

The result shows...

`at product ABU43E
    ..
    ..
    ..
    at product AXF40J
    at product ACZ16C
    2014-04-21 17:32:07 +0700
    at product ABZ14C
    at product AXF90E
    at product ABZ14B
    at product ABK43E
    at product ABK01A
    2014-04-21 17:32:24 +0700
    2014-04-21 17:32:24 +0700
    at product ABU05G
    at product ABZABF
    2014-04-21 17:32:28 +0700
    2014-04-21 17:32:28 +0700
    2014-04-21 17:32:28 +0700
    2014-04-21 17:32:28 +0700
    2014-04-21 17:32:28 +0700
    2014-04-21 17:32:28 +0700
      %   cumulative   self              self     total
     time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
     32.54     1.99      1.99       43    46.40   265.60  Array#each
     24.17     3.48      1.48    41075     0.04     0.04  File#mtime
     13.72     4.32      0.84       43    19.AX    19.AX  Dir#glob
      9.13     4.88      0.AX    41075     0.01     0.03  Time#-
      8.14     5.38      0.50    41075     0.01     0.01  Float#quo
      6.65     5.79      0.41    41075     0.01     0.01  Time#now
      2.06     5.91      0.13    41084     0.00     0.00  Time#initialize
      1.79     6.02      0.11    41075     0.00     0.00  Float#<
      1.79     6.13      0.11    41075     0.00     0.00  Float#/
      0.00     6.13      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Array#join
      0.00     6.13      0.00       51     0.00     0.00  Kernel.puts
      0.00     6.13      0.00       51     0.00     0.00  IO#puts
      0.00     6.13      0.00      102     0.00     0.00  IO#write
      0.00     6.13      0.00       42     0.00     0.00  File#join
      0.00     6.13      0.00       43     0.00     0.00  Dir#chdir
      0.00     6.13      0.00       10     0.00     0.00  Class#new
      0.00     6.13      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  MyCollector#initialize
      0.00     6.13      0.00        9     0.00     0.00  Integer#round
      0.00     6.13      0.00        9     0.00     0.00  Time#to_s
      0.00     6.13      0.00        1     0.00  6131.00  MyCollector#collect
      0.00     6.13      0.00        1     0.00  6131.00  #toplevel
    [Finished in 477.5s]`

It turn out that it take up to 7 mins to walk over each files in each directories. then call mtime.
Although my .txt file is 2Mb, it should not suppose to take time that long, no ?

Any suggestion, pls ?

Comment: Code looks ok. I'd suggest to comment out processing code and add profiling puts with timestamps to actually find out WHERE it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on `mtime` is not robust. In fact, Rails switched from using mtime to hash in naming the versions of asset files.

You should keep a list of file-hash pair. That can be obtained like this:

```
require "digest"

file_hash_pair =
Dir.glob("LOGS/**/*")
.select{|f| File.file?(f)}
.map{|f| [f, Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(File.read(f))]}
```

and perhaps you can keep the content of this in a file as YAML. You can run the code above each time, and whenever `file_hash_pair` is different from the previous value, you can tell that there was a change. If `file_hash_pair.transpose[0]` changed, then you can tell there was a file manipulation. If for a particular `[file, hash]` pair, the `hash` changed, then you can tell that the file `file` changed.

Comment: Really? Reading large file from network share just to check if it was changed? I hope you are not implementing any production code.